# How to show Spinning Wheel or Busy Icon while waiting in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, progress, shinydashboard

Hey i've just started working with R and Shiny.
Trying to make a dashboard which displays different charts.
As there is a lot of data to process, the plots or charts take some time to display after the action button is clicked i.e. "launch Campaign' 
Is there anyway i could show a spinning wheel or a loading icon  in the white blank space, while this delay takes place? [Dashboard with blank space on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRPJ4.jpg)

Comment: Have you looked into here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/progress-bar-example.html ?

Comment: This has been already covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004302/shiny-app-busy-indicator Basically you are looking for conditionalPanel in the first approximation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shiny app busy indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004302/shiny-app-busy-indicator)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There is wonderful `shinycssloaders` package https://github.com/andrewsali/shinycssloaders, now maintained here https://github.com/daattali/shinycssloaders, which does what you want:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinycssloaders)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  actionButton("plot","plot"),
  plotOutput("Test") %>% withSpinner(color="#0dc5c1")
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  

  data <- eventReactive(input$plot,{
    rnorm(1:100000)
  })
  
  output$Test <- renderPlot({
    plot(data())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: works with textOutput as well. Great Stuff! `textOutput("t1")%>% withSpinner(color="#0dc5c1")`

Comment: https://dreamrs.github.io/shinybusy/ IMO this is the easiest solution. Requires only one line of code

Comment: @bodega18 for the win!!!